# << unmatched error from different user

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a ksh function that runs good like this:

```
td_query () { bteq << EOF |grep '^>' |sed -e "s/^>//" 
user/pass
    DATABASE db;
    $1
.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
.EXIT
EOF
}
```

But when copy to another dir and run it under a different user, I get this error:

```
-ksh: .: syntax error: `<<' unmatched
```

why would it work under one user and not the other?

What else I can't figure out is if i login as the user it works under, then go to the other directory I just copied it too and try to run it from there, it doesn't work either...

Comment: I set it to the same chmod but still no luck..

Comment: figured it out...the file was encoded as a windows file during transfer for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

you have a stray space in your heredoc redirection:

```
bteq << -EOF
       ^^
```

should be

```
bteq <<- EOF
       ^^
```

The hyphen belongs to the redirection operator. See [the ksh93 man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html#Input/Output) (or [ksh88](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html#Input/Output))

Comment: whoops..sorry, made a code error, corrected it up top....I was trying various things to get it to work but even that does not work...

Comment: As the other user, type `set -x` then execute the function. What do you see?

Comment: yes, but does the extra debugging output reveal anything to you?

Comment: The function gets invoked by td_query "sql query" later in the script...file was coded as windows for some reason when I transfered it, changed the coding to unix as stated above